# What is this subfloor and tile prep

Tags: subfloor

I removed the tile in my bathroom.  The top photo shows what it looks like below the removed tile. The bottom photo shows a closeup profile, near the toilet flange. It is 1 inch think with wood plywood at the bottom. The checkboard pattern seems like paper when I peel it. Tt is is very hard and solid and only chipped away in some spots over the entire area.

My questions are: 1. Can I tile over this? 2. What would be the surface prep.? [image]

Thank you
[image]

Comment: That pattern looks like the backs of tiles, where you'd backbutter.

Comment: It looks to me like the tiles were laid down as sheets that had some sort of plastic mesh holding several tiles together in larger squares. Usually this is done on small mosaic tiles, but your larger tile pattern could have been purchased this way. Easier to install large 12x12" tile sheets rather than all the little pieces to make up the pattern.

Comment: That makes sense that it was a paper type mesh to hold the small  tiles together for easier install..  They were the smaller square tiles removed.  So what I have is a 1 inch thickness  cement board, thin layer of mortar (the white) along with the paper (square pattern).    Can I place a new layer of cement board over this and then tile over that??  I would screw the new cement board to the joints ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have backer board looking at the edge of the toilet hole.
Since the pattern feels like paper it was probably a mastic put on the tile or back buttered as Huesmann  stated but We normally put adhesive on the bottom surface with a notched trowel.

I would attempt to peal / scrape this material up since it has come up in areas your new tile may not set as well.

If the material is paper thin you mentioned felt like paper and you are using large tiles you probably can tile over this without it showing.
If it is a mastic many are water based but make one heck of a mess if it gets wet , it easily plugs sanding belts so if it won’t scrape up clean the area and overlay with your adhesive or thinset on the surface with a notched trowel.

Back buttering is coating the tile with the adhesive or thin set then scraping most of it off it wets the surface and you get a much better bond.